# Groovy closure won't take two different classes that implement same interface?

Tags: groovy, interface, closures

I'm using a third party Java API via groovy, and am facing a problem with a closure I've written. The problem *appears* to be that the closure is compiled to have a signature that takes a concrete class as opposed to the interface I want it take.

So, we have two classes `A` and `B` that implement interface `IInterface`.

`IInterface` has a method called `parent`. The parent of any object in `A` or `B` is an object in `B`. *(For brevity, we will ignore the issue of reaching the root of this tree).*

If I implement the following:

```
static def foo = { IInterface obj ->
    assert obj.parent() in IInterface
    foo(obj.parent())
}
```

and then call it with an object in `A`, then it will fail when I expect it to recurse, with

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
packagename.Runner$__clinit__closure5.foo() is applicable for argument types: (B)
values: ...
```

It looks like `foo()` has been compiled to take an `A` not an `IInterface`. Have I diagnosed this correctly? Am I missing something obvious?

For completeness, `groovy --version` reports "Groovy Version: 2.1.6 JVM: 1.7.0_09-icedtea Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux".

Comment: Are you sure `B` implements `IInterface`?

Comment: Show case `A` and `B` signifying *The parent of any object in A or B is an object in B.*

Comment: Can you come up with a brief example that shows the issue and is repeatable by us?

Comment: @Normal has pointed out the real problem - it's not to do with the types - it's recursion that doesn't work. I've marked his answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the same issue as 
[Recursion with closures in Groovy 2.1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764834/recursion-with-closures-in-groovy-2-1-9)

try this:

```
def foo 
foo = { IInterface obj ->
    assert obj.parent() in IInterface
    foo(obj.parent())
}
```

Comment: Thanks - as I'm using a static closure (it's only meant to be a quick bit of work) the second solution (wrapping the inner in another closure) in the link you provided worked.  A quick check in groovyConsole shows the problem is still there in 2.2.1.